# QSqlDatabase hello world application fails to debug

Tags: qt, postgresql, qt-creator, qtsql

I'm attempting a QSqlDatabase hello world application using PostgreSQL. My environment is as follows: Windows 7 64-bit, Qt 4.8.2, PostgreSQL 9.0.13. The following code compiles, but will not debug, i.e. when I place a break on the QSqlDatabase::drivers() line, but the code exits with an exception. The application runs as expected when I comment out this line. Any suggestions?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtSql/QtSql>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication prog(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow *mainWin = new QMainWindow;
    QStringList drvlst = QSqlDatabase::drivers();  // <-- problem!
    mainWin->show();

    return prog.exec();
}
```

Comment: Do you have `QtSql4.dll` in the execution directory?

Comment: ... or `QtSql4d.dll` if you're using the debug libraries.

Comment: No, I don't. I do have qsqlpsql4.dll and qsqlpsqld4.dll in these directories. Also, while running Dependency Walker, it does produce errors on the qtsqld4.dll - specifically, the ssleay32.dll, libeay32.dll and kernel32.dll. Looks like a x86 v. x64 issue?

Comment: Here's a good one. Using Dependency Walker, I (or we, thanks Noah) was able to identify that Qt was using the openvpn "version" of libeay32.dll, as this directory reference in the PATH environment variable was towards the beginning of the list. Moving the openvpn reference to the end of the PATH solved the problem.

Comment: Put that as an answer then and close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another example of DLL hell and how Dependency Walker can be a great tool for diagnosing potential bugs of this nature. Again, in this case, the linker was traversing the PATH environment variable to find QTSQLD4.DLL library dependencies. The linker found the openVPN SSLEAY32.DLL (which is actually 64 bit) instead of the postgreSQL version of SSLEAY32.DLL. Moving the openVPN url to the end of the PATH environment variable resolved this problem.